# How do I quickly update a value in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

OKay, i have 1 key:value in firebase

```
hp_current: 1000
```

I want that when the button is clicked, the value decreases by a given number, for example, by 20
I decided to try it like this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("raids/$raid_squad/").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener{
 val raid = it.getValue(Raid::class.java)
val currenthp = raid!!.hp_current
 val newhp = currenthp - damage
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("raids/$raid_squad/hp_current/").setValue(newhp.toInt())})
```

But the problem appears when 2 or 3 clients simultaneously click on the button and the HP does not decrease for all 3 clicks, but only for 1 of 3 clicks. Because to reduce it, it takes the old value and it turns out that it does not reduce it in any way because of other clients

I'm new to this, please help what ideas do you have?

p.s I have no problems with saving to the database! There is a problem with the fact that a lot of people should be able to just take and decrease 1 and the same value

Comment: You need a transaction for that, as explained in the duplicate answer.

Comment: I have no problems with saving to the database! There is a problem with the fact that a lot of people should be able to just take and decrease 1 and the same value @Alex Mamo

Comment: ServerValue.increment?

Comment: it's for JS. not Android / kotlin

Comment: No, it's for Android.

Comment: @Alex Mamo it didn't help, it just got worse

Comment: "it just got worse" is really hard to help with. Please update your question showing what you tried, and what the problem is that you're getting. I also highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it has great guidance on how to maximize the chances that someone can help.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen  I have already solved my problem to some extent, I decided to make a different value for each one and when displaying it, I just took and combined all the individual values